# How can I make CookieConsent by Insites to show up only for users in the EU?

Tags: cookies, cookieconsent

How can I make CookieConsent by Insites to show up only for users in the EU? I used the developers' wizard to design it but can't find an option to hide it for users outside the EU. Bear in mind that I have no programming skills except for some basic html and css

Comment: Note that the `CookieConsent` widget doesn't actually disable cookies by itself automatically, you need to follow the instructions on this page: https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/disabling-cookies/

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this without programming I fear. There's no "build-in" solution to do so. One approach could be to use some geoip database (like https://ipstack.com/) to find the geographic location of the ip. If it's in the EU, include the cookieconsent code in your HTML, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

The CookieConsent documentation page has a section entirely devoted to determining the location of the visitor: https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/location-services-cookie-law/

Somewhat ironically, getting the location of the user requires their consent again (at least if you're using client-side location APIs). An alternative is to use an IP geolocation service/API, note that these aren't usually free - or accurate.